# How to use login callback for application client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm writing a Swing application client (it's runs over webstart, and I'm using glassfish). In the application class I have:

```
@EJB private static MyBean myBean;
```

and in `MyBean` I have:

```
@Remote
public interface MyBean {
  public int getRand();
}

@DeclareRoles(("admin"))
@Stateful(name="MyBean")
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
  @RolesAllowed(("admin"))
  public int getRand() {
    return 9; // Guaranteed to be random
  }
}
```

So far so good. I start the app using `javaws http://server/app/app-client`, it asks for user/pass and authenticates properly (using the fileRealm from glassfish).

I have two problems:

- It seems to try to authenticate right away (when the bean is referenced) rather than when I try to call the method. I can live with this.
- I want to use my own login dialog. Partly for aesthetic reasons, but also for graceful error handling, retries, etc

So I need to specify a callback. Using `new LoginContext("fileRealm", myCallback)` I get an error about no login modules for fileRealm. I've tried various mixtures of examples from the net, but very few are designed to application clients.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've solved the second (and most important issue) by Adding the following to `application-client.xml`:

```
<application-client...>
  ...
  <callback-handler>package.name.ClassName</callback-handler>
</application-client>
```

Comment: After reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty/36904#36904, +1 to push your answer and feedback to the top ;)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to try to authenticate right away (when the bean is referenced) rather than when I try to call the method. I can live with this.

This is because it needs to be authenticated to create an RMI context.

Comment: It's nice to have an explanation, but I desperately need to know how to get my own dialog to appear.